# Is there a lint rule for ensuring nested JavaScript objects are separated with &&?

Tags: javascript, object, nested, lint

I'm often finding problems in my code that relate to nested objects not existing. Here is an example.

```
var test = { one: { two: { three: 3 } } };
console.log(test.one.two.three.four.five);
```

This will cause an error and the correct way I'd like the code to prevent this error is like this

```
console.log(test && test.one && test.one.two && test.one.two.three && 
test.one.two.three.four && test.one.two.three.four.five);
```

Is there a lint rule that I can apply to make sure I check these nested objects?

Comment: No, the linter cannot know when an object property is optional and needs to be checked or not. (It would be a giant pain if you enforced this on *every* property access, there are so many legitimate use cases). This is what you need a *type checker* for that knows about the type of object whose properties you are accessing.

Comment: Also, there are saner ways than longer and longer property chains and `&&`, e.g. `((test || {}).one || {}).two...`, or `['one', 'two', ...].reduce((o, p) => o && o[p], test)`.

Comment: @Bergi ok, so something like TypeScript then? Thanks

Comment: @deceze I've looked at that before, but I just don't see the advantage. It is longer and less straightforward than just using `&&` IMHO

Comment: You could consider polyfilling or using directly lodash's get https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get, for instance `_.get(test, 'one.two.three.four.five', defaultValue)`

Comment: Say what now? Which one is longer? https://pastebin.com/N9BfddML

Comment: I would strongly consider what I'm doing if I end up with nested objects four or five levels deep.

Comment: @deceze I stand corrected. Not longer.

Comment: @DevinFields mostly when I run into deeply nested objects I'm using a database to store some configuration. I think you make a good point, though.

Comment: @JoshJoe Yes, Typescript or Flow are the first that comes to my mind